# Watermark for Textbox in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I set watermark for a texbox in MVC3 .Also if there are multiple textboxes in a web page, how do you write different watermark text for each  textbox?

```
       <%:Html.TextBoxFor(mdl => mdl.inputTextSearch, Model.inputTextSearch )%>
```

Appreciate your response

Comment: Watermark in what sense, a javascript solution or the new HTML5 [placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder)?

Answer (score 20):

If I understand your question, you can just pass in:

```
new { placeholder = "my watermark" }
```

as the htmlAttributes parameter in Html.TextBoxFor.

Edit:

You can also add support for older browsers by using Javascript as outlined here:

http://www.standardista.com/html5-placeholder-attribute-script

Comment: I tried that earlier and iam getting this error,  No overload for method 'TextBoxFor' takes 3 arguments

Comment: Try this: <%:Html.TextBoxFor(mdl => mdl.inputTextSearch, new { placeholder = "my watermark" })%>

Answer (score 3):

I usually just use the following jquery,for MVC project on fields which need a watermark: (the code compatible with IE 6 - 9, Firefox 2 - 4, safari 4.

```
 $('#UserSearch').Watermark("Search term", "#fff");
```

/// JQuery Plugin code.

```
(function($) {
var map=new Array();
$.Watermark = {
    ShowAll:function(){
        for (var i=0;i<map.length;i++){
            if(map[i].obj.val()==""){
                map[i].obj.val(map[i].text);                    
                map[i].obj.css("color",map[i].WatermarkColor);
            }else{
                map[i].obj.css("color",map[i].DefaultColor);
            }
        }
    },
    HideAll:function(){
        for (var i=0;i<map.length;i++){
            if(map[i].obj.val()==map[i].text)
                map[i].obj.val("");                 
        }
    }
}

$.fn.Watermark = function(text,color) {
    if(!color)
        color="#aaa";
    return this.each(
        function(){     
            var input=$(this);
            var defaultColor=input.css("color");
            map[map.length]={text:text,obj:input,DefaultColor:defaultColor,WatermarkColor:color};
            function clearMessage(){
                if(input.val()==text)
                    input.val("");
                input.css("color",defaultColor);
            }

            function insertMessage(){
                if(input.val().length==0 || input.val()==text){
                    input.val(text);
                    input.css("color",color);   
                }else
                    input.css("color",defaultColor);                
            }

            input.focus(clearMessage);
            input.blur(insertMessage);                              
            input.change(insertMessage);

            insertMessage();
        }
    );
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The only problem with this approach is when the user does not enter anything in the watermarked field, the field validates ok since the watermark is perceived to be the value.

Comment: I handled this by removing watermark onSubmit HideAll. 
I've found a more complete version that the above plugin I put together. http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/. Hopefully this helps you out.

Answer (score 3):

Using the MVC 3 standard, and an HTML5 compliant browser you can do:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(mdl => mdl.inputTextSearch, new { placeholder = "my watermark" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this Jquery .You need to create an image with the watermark text.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            /*Watermark for date fields*/

             if ($("#dob").val() == "") {
                $("#dob").css("background", "#ebebeb url('/Content/images/DateWaterMark.png') no-repeat 1px 0px");
            }

            $("#dob").focus(function () {
                if (watermark == 'MM/DD/YYYY') {
                    $("#dob").css("background-image", "none");
                    $("#dob").css("background-color", "#fff");
                }
            }).blur(function () {
                if (this.value == "") {
                    $("#dob").css("background", "#ebebeb url('/Content/images/DateWaterMark.png') no-repeat 1px 0px");
                }
            });

            $("#dob").change(function () {
                if (this.value.length > 0) {
                    $("#dob").css("background", "#fff");
                }
            });
}
```