# Razor textbox, "value" property not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Watermark for Textbox in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445274/watermark-for-textbox-in-mvc3)

Im switching my HTML code from basic html to use html helpers and Html.TextBoxFor...

This is my old code

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="Phone" name="Phone" id="cust-cellphone" class="tonedDown" />
```

And this is the new version

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Customer.Phone_Personal, new { @class = "text-adr-fld tonedDown", @value = "Phone", @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Everything is working fine, except that the Value property is gone. What I mean is that it's not showing as a default predefined value inside the textbox.
I read that you can use Placeholder, but it doesnt seem to work with IE9 (which is a requirement from my client).

So the question is, how do I add input Value property to the TextboxFor method that works with IE9?

Edit:
There might be a possible workaround somehow.
My original purpose with this is to display a "placeholder like value", ie a default value which shows what the user is supposed to type in the textbox. E.g. the textbox that handles phonenumber should display "Phone", until the user clicks and enters a value.

Does anyone know another way of doing this (except "placeholder" and "value")?

Comment: there are plenty of work around using jquery for this, check [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6445274/1182982) on SO. also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5120257/1182982) out

Comment: Use Value instead value.

Answer (score 1):

u can set the default value to your model, and then your piece of code will work, else you can  try using

```
    @Html.TextBox("Phone_Personal", "Phone", new { @class = "text-adr-fld tonedDown", @disabled = "disabled" }).
```

If u want to use TextBoxFor, then using

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#Phone_Personal").val("Phone"); // replace Phone_Personal with the ID of the textbox
   });
```

Comment: Ive tried both of these and neither work =(

Comment: Even the Jquery approach didn't help? What is the ID generated for the Textbox?

Comment: Nope =(  The id is Customer_Phone_Personal

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't pass the model to View method :

```
 return View(model);
```

Or,the model is null.

Comment: Im passing a class in the return statment: return View(order); and then Im specifying the model in the top of the cshtml file: @model Mylibrary.Web.Order

Comment: Do I need a specific Model class that I pass to View? Or does my way of passing a class work in the same way?

Comment: Thats good,but set a breakpoint at the returning view statement ,and check if your model (Order) that you are passing to "View(order)" is null or not.

Comment: The Order object isnt null. But all the field values are (ofc, the user hasnt inputed them yet)...

Comment: hmmm...try setting those properties to default values,for example:if the property is string,set it as String.Empty.

Comment: There is an attribute called "[DefaultValue()]" ,try to write it above "Order"'s properties.
check this link plz:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779881/annotating-properties-on-a-model-with-default-values

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx